# Aligning cells in two columns but also maintaining the position of cells in the third

Tags: excel, alignment

I am seeking your assistance on how I can align cells in two columns but also maintaining the position of cells in the third. I tried this formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0)))` but it only aligns two columns. Please see the example I did manually here so as you can understand what I am looking for: https://www.dropbox.com/s/14718nta8ljwtio/Example.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

In column G use this formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$2:$B$27,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$27,0)),"")
```

And in column H use this formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX($C$2:$C$27,MATCH(G2,$B$2:$B$27,0)),"")
```

[image]

If you are using a newer version of Excel you can do this with just one formula in column G, and it will spill into column H

```
=FILTER($B$2:$C$27,$B$2:$B$27=F2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jody, this is exactly what I needed. I appreciate a lot